# Can I include Custom data in a AWS Cloudwatch Alert?

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, amazon-cloudwatch, devops

I'm using AWS Cloudwatch to monitor application log files on my AWS EC2 instances. Is there a way to include Custom data (I.E. stack trace) in the Cloudwatch Alert when it is triggered by the metric I define?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up routing the alert event to a REST service I wrote rather than to the SNS notification group. The web service uses the "event name" and timestamp to generate a custom notification. It pulls diagnostic information from several services, including our ELK stack, and includes it in the custom notification along with the typical Cloudwatch Alert data. The web service then sends the custom notification to the original SNS notification group to be distributed.